# Weird pointer to array syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the logic motivating `int (*arr)[5];` to declare `arr` as a pointer to an array of 5 elements, whereas `int *arr[5]` declares `arr` as an array of 5 pointers ? Especially given that `*` has low priority (unsure about this part since it isn't used as the dereferencing operator) ?

Comment: Consistency with the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: C declarators use essentially the same syntax that you would use to access the variable being defined.

Comment: Declares (without allocating) a pointer to an array of int(s). The 
pointer to the array must be dereferenced to access the value of each 
element.

Comment: I found it also pretty complicated, and I am not ashamed to use an intermediate `typedef` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In both declarations and expressions, postfix operators like `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so a declaration like

```
T *a[N];
```

is *parsed* as

```
T *(a[N]);
```

Thus

```
   a       -- a is
   a[N]    -- an N-element array of
  *a[N]    -- pointer to
T *a[N];   -- T
```

If you want to declare `a` as a pointer *to an array*, then you need to explicitly group the `*` operator with `a`:

```
T (*a)[N];
```

Thus:

```
    a      -- a is
  (*a)     -- a pointer to
  (*a)[N]  -- an N-element array of
T (*a)[N]; -- T
```

As luck would have it, you're far more likely to be using an arrays of pointers than pointers to arrays, so it makes sense that the "simpler" form of declaration results in that type.

Answer (score 1):

You've already stated the reason: `*` has lower precedence than `[]`.
So

```
int *a[5];
```

is

```
int *(a[5]);
```

meaning that `a` is an array first, and what it's an array of is pointers.

To me, this is a fine result.  I declare arrays of pointers all the time, and `int a[5]` is convenient syntax.  Trying to type `int (*a)[5]` feels very strange, but that's okay, because I never declare pointers to arrays (because they're virtually never useful).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the logic motivating int (*arr)[5];

It depends on the context. For example if you have a two-dimensional array then you can use a pointer of such a type as an iterator.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a[2][5] = 
    {
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for (int(*row)[5] = a; row != a + 2; ++row)
    {
        for (int *col = *row; col != *row + 5; ++col)
        {
            printf("%d ", *col);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or if you have a function that declares its parameter as a two-dimensional array as for example

```
void f( int a[][5], size_t n );
```

then the parameter implicitly is adjusted to pointer of the type `int ( * )[5]`

Take into account that if you have an array like this

```
int * a[5];
```

then a pointer to the array will look

```
int * ( *p )[5] = &a;
```

While if you  have an array like this

```
int a[5];
```

then a pointer to the array will look like

```
int ( *p )[5] = &a;
```